# I can not find a web content in my beautiful soup sacrapper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a scrapper that collects the number of datasets currently listed on [this site](https://www.data.gov).

Check out my code.

```
from requests import exceptions
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


site='https://data.gov/index.html/'

try:
    html_content=requests.get(site).text

except exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print('there is a problem with reaching this site')

soup=BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

    
needed_text=soup.find('label',{'for':'search-header'})

for text in needed_text:
    try:
        final_text=text.find('a').attrs['href']
        print('there are {} data sets currently listed on data.gov'.format(final_text.get_text()))
    except:
        continue
```

how ever when i run this code, it do not get any result.

I printed the HTML script of the website, and I can not find the particular data I need. I can see it on the browser, but i can not find it in my IDE.

Please help.

Comment: The dats is injected using JS. You can't scrape that using beattifulsoup.

Comment: No, it's not @0stone0. The part the OP is looking for is in the source HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is wrong and returns `404`. [See it yourself](https://data.gov/index.html/).

Also, moving the `soup` part of the code to the `try except` block might be a good idea. Finally, no need to use a `for loop`, as there's only one element with the data you want.

Try this:

```py
import requests
from requests import exceptions
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


site = 'https://data.gov'

try:
    html_content = requests.get(site).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
    needed_text = soup.select_one("small > a[href]").getText()
    print(needed_text)
except exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print('there is a problem with reaching this site')
```

Output:

```
335,221 datasets
```